Why is `isr_common_stub` not calling my `isr_handler` function?
I want to enable IDT in x86_64 OS so I have written isr_common_stub function
isr_common_stub:
    call save_registers

    mov eax, 0x10             ; Load the kernel data segment descriptor
    mov ds, eax
    mov es, eax
    mov fs, eax
    mov gs, eax

    mov rdi, rsp             ; Pass the current stack pointer to `isr_handler`
    cld                      ; Required by AMD64 System V ABI
    call isr_handler
    
    add rsp, 16
    call restore_registers
    sti
    iretq                     ; Return from Interrupt

Full code in here
If registers_t structure is
typedef struct registers
{
    uint64_t ds, es, fs, gs;                       // Segment registers 
    uint64_t r15, r14, r13, r12, r11, r10, r9, r8; // General-purpose registers
    uint64_t rdi, rsi, rbp, rdx, rcx, rbx, rax;    // General-purpose registers

    uint64_t int_no, err_code;                     // Interrupt number and error code

    uint64_t iret_rip, iret_cs, iret_rflags, iret_rsp, iret_ss; // CPU state
} registers_t; 


is this proper way to call isr_handler?

The bad commit is here: https://github.com/baponkar/KeblaOS/commit/14902827c4fc37c297bb1c15b8bbf475fe91a409 and was made by a user funofphysics. As a result you can't even make your project. It appears to be a bad merge that had unresolved problems that were never fixed (thus all the lines beginning with <<<<<< and >>>>>>)

I'm not sure you saw my email response back to you. I'd help you but your Github project has major breakage because of a bad commit. One thing I mentioned to you in my email is that you can't call a function to push (or pop registers) because the return address is placed on the stack. It would work if you converted restore_registers and save_registers into macros. As well you don't need an sti at the end. adding 16 to RSP needs to be done as the last thing before the iretq.

I see you resolved the bad commit. Thanks. I have made a pull request here with my suggested fixes: https://github.com/baponkar/KeblaOS/pull/4 . I changed to the use of macros to save/restore the registers; I moved add rsp, 16 to before the iretq;  removed the unneeded sti before iretq; pushed the IRQ interrupt number without clobbering the RAX register.

I see that you manually applied some of my changes. I had to update my pull request (see updated changes here: https://github.com/baponkar/KeblaOS/pull/4/files), You have one major problem not fixed (the registers won't be properly restored as a result). You are adding 16 to RSP before you restore the registers. This will lead to problems. It needs to be done after you restore the registers. As well, division by 0 is undefined behaviour in C. Your code that generates division by 0 (now commented out) could be replaced by inline assembly that causes division by 0.

@MichaelPetch I am grateful for your help. The keyboard handler is not working although before it was functional. Can you please suggest me anything need to update?

Because you don't enable interrupts anymore. A good place to do it is at the end of init_idt by calling enable_interrupts. I have committed that change and some other cleanup in this new pull request:  https://github.com/baponkar/KeblaOS/pull/5
